deploy into multiple Servers one Project with Intellij idea
I have serval servers (different locations) , connected to one database, I wrote web Application Base on Java/Jakarta and the platform serve as web server is glassfish , One Problem I have its How can I deploy my application into these server from Intellij idea with run configuration?
In other Hand I have static files that ship on ftp to servers work with my application, some of them is private and some is public access , so I need a way that can send it to multiple ftp.
I didn't found any way for send via ftp just use network drive, that can be done for me.
For my web application that is war file I know I can use cluster but one of my server is local.
Servers : (1x)Ubuntu 22.04 ,(2x) windows Server 2022 , Windows 10(localhost)
Network : one local address(localhost with no static public Ip access) , 
Glassfish: latest Version

What I need :
Is there any options in Intellij idea that can with on action -> save : upload into multiple Servers via ftp?
Is there any options in Intellij idea that can with run Configuration deploy war file into multiple glassfish Servers?
Limitations : Can't use Glassfish cluster , Can't Use Network Drive.

IntelliJ is a development environment, you shouldn’t upload applications to production from it. Instead, it’s better if you have a script that does that. IntelliJ can run shell scripts or maven goals,if you use maven for building and add a goal to upload files to FTP server or via GlassFish asadmin command.

Thank mate, but its an advise not an answer to my questions, I agree with you but some time we need work on hot project and after all the things good to go jump in product mode. like critical issue or important fix bugs. that Several time need update and fix it in real time without stop.

IntelliJ does’t support that, without a custom script or maven setup. You can use asadmin redeploy command to redeploy apps without restart.
